# How do you reference other branches of a python package?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I'm trying to create a python package where code in one branch references code in a parallel branch.

For example:

```
my_package/
 ├─utils/
 │  └─foo.py
 └─other_branch/
    └─bar.py
```

How can I reference code from `utils.foo.py` in `other_branch.bar.py`?

Comment: `my_package.branch_1.foo.whatever`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `my_package` is a valid package, you can just import from it as usual:

```
import my_package.branch_1.foo
```

Alternatively, you can use relative imports:

```
import ..branch_1.foo
```

For details, check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).

Answer (score 2):

It's usually bad practice to do something like that. Hierarchy should be a hierarchy logically as well and structurally.
When designing a project right, each directory will only need packages from it's sub-directories.
That being said, you should be able to do something like that:

`foo.py`:

```
from ..branch_2 import bar
```

You should make sure you have `__init__.py` in all directories.

Comment: Good answer. Good point about the hierarchy. I would probably recommend switching back to absolute imports in such cases (importing from parent or sibling packages).